# Unity Switched weapon not syncing PUN 2

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I managed to get my shooting synchronised however i cant figure out how to sync weapon switching (using the same method, rpc)
the problem is that whenever i switch weapons, it doesnt show on my second screen.

```
public class WeaponHolder : MonoBehaviour
{   
    PhotonView view;

    public int selectedWeapon = 0;

    void Start()
    {
        view = GetComponent<PhotonView>();
        if(!view.IsMine)
        {
            return;
        }
        SelectWeapon();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(!view.IsMine)
        {
            return;
        }
        if(FindObjectsOfType<weaponScript>()[0].isReloading == true)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            view.RPC("switchWeapon", RpcTarget.All);
        }
    }

    [PunRPC]
    public void switchWeapon()
    {
        if(!view.IsMine)
        {
            return;
        }
        int previousSelectedWeapon = selectedWeapon;
        if(Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") > 0f)
        {
            if(selectedWeapon >= transform.childCount - 1)
            {
                selectedWeapon = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                selectedWeapon++;
            }
        }

        if(Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") < 0f)
        {
            if(selectedWeapon <= 0)
            {
                selectedWeapon = transform.childCount - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                selectedWeapon--;
            }
        }

        if(previousSelectedWeapon != selectedWeapon)
        {
            SelectWeapon();
        }
    }

    public void SelectWeapon()
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (Transform weapon in transform)
        {
            if(i ==  selectedWeapon)
            {
                weapon.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            }
            else
            {
                weapon.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

(used brackeys' tutorial for weapon switching)
i did the exact same with my shooting script and that worked, i have a photon view component on my gameobject where i have this script attached to it

Answer (score 0):

Within an RPC you wouldn't want to check

```
if(!view.IsMine){ return; }
```

then what would be the purpose of sending this as RPC to everyone? You could simply call this only on your device ;) you want this happen on all other clients as well.

You will want to restructure your methods and execute `SwitchWeapon` only on your device directly without an RPC and then rather pass on `SelectWeapon(int)` via RPC to everyone and pass in the new index.

```
void Update()
{
    if(!view.IsMine)
    {
        return;
    }

    if(FindObjectsOfType<weaponScript>()[0].isReloading)
    {
        return;
    }

    switchWeapon();
}

private void switchWeapon()
{
    if(!view.IsMine)
    {
        return;
    }

    var scroll = Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");
    if(scroll > 0f)
    {
        selectedWeapon = (selectedWeapon + 1) % transform.childCount;
        view.RPC(nameof(SelectWeapon), RpcTarget.All, selectedWeapon);
    }
    else if(scroll < 0f)
    {
        selectedWeapon--;
        if(selectedWeapon < 0)
        {
            selectedWeapon = transform.childCount - 1;
        }

        view.RPC(nameof(SelectWeapon), RpcTarget.All, selectedWeapon);
    }
}

[PunRPC]
public void SelectWeapon(int newWeapon)
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach(Transform weapon in transform)
    {
        weapon.gameObject.SetActive(i == newWeapon);
    }
    i++;
}
```

and also in `Start` do

```
view.RPC(nameof(SelectWeapon), RpcTarget.AllBuffered, selectedWeapon);
```

Comment: ive got a few errors i have no clue how to fix,  https://imgur.com/nf64KcD

Comment: @Evolight you have to adjust the call in `Start` accordingly .. and I think I had the order of parameters wrong in the `RPC` ;)

Comment: that fixed nearly everything, great! however i still get an error here
```weapon.gameObject.SetActive(i == newWeapon);```


'object' does not contain a definition for 'gameObject' and no accessible extension method 'gameObject' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found

Comment: @Evolight oh yeah the enumerator of Transform is not typed .. you have to explicitly use `Transform` instead of `var`

Comment: no errors, quickly tested it out but when i start the game, all weapons are active and when i scroll up or down, all weapons deactivate and i get an index out of bound error

Comment: I suggest you debug this .. I don't know enough about your project to answer this properly .. seems that your available weapon count is not synchronized?